# std::auto_ptr becomes invalid after being passed to a function by value

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, auto-ptr

I've got the following sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <auto_ptr.h>

class A
{
public:
    A(){ std::cout << "A ctor" << std::endl;}
    ~A() {std::cout << "A dtor" << std::endl;}
    void bar(){std::cout << "bar()" << std::endl;}
};

void foo(std::auto_ptr<A> a)
{
    std::cout << "foo()" << std::endl ;
}

int main()
{
    std::auto_ptr<A> a(new A());
    a->bar();
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
A ctor
bar()
A dtor
```

Now if I call `foo(a)`, `a` will be destructed before calling `bar()`:

```
int main()
{
    std::auto_ptr<A> a(new A());
    foo(a);
    a->bar();
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
A ctor
foo()
A dtor
bar()
```

Why is `a` destructed after `foo()` is called?

Another thing I don't understand is that if I pass the parameter to `foo` by reference, `a` will not be destructed after calling `foo()`:

```
void foo(std::auto_ptr<A> &a)
{
    std::cout << "foo()" << std::endl ;
}

int main()
{
    std::auto_ptr<A> a(new A());
    foo(a);
    a->bar();
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
A ctor
foo()
bar()
A dtor
```

How is passing by reference affecting the lifetime of `auto_ptr`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`auto_ptr` steals ownership upon copying. When you copy it, the copy now holds the pointer to the object, and the original holds nothing.

It's also a deprecated concept. If you have access to C++11, use `unique_ptr` instead.

Comment: unique_ptr is also moving ownership. don't you mean shared_ptr in his case?

Comment: @itwasntpete The difference is that `std::unique_ptr` does not have a copy constructor, only a move copy constructor. So you have to call `move` on an instance in order to transfer ownership (or pass a temporary or rvalue). `shared_ptr` would not be the right replacement for `auto_ptr`.

Answer (score 2):

The auto_ptr has semantics of transfer ownership. If you pass it by value then ownership is transfered to a temporary object which, of course, will be destroyed when leaves the scope.

Answer (score 1):

The std::auto_ptr is usually not what people expect, the idea was that that it is a safer concept since the ptr is cleared as soon as the object get out of scope. So your "new A" will not be leaked even in case of multiple returns / exception thrown etc.

However as you shown it is also very easy to cause illegal memory access because two auto_ptrs sharing a single pointer is a recipe for disaster.

If you just want a ptr that you can use and not worry about releasing you should use unique_ptr. unique_ptr can't be copied. So you can pass a reference of it but not copy it.

Usually the most useful construct is the shared_ptr which allows multiple owners to share a the same ptr and ensures it will be released when all the owners go out of scope.

All of these are part of c++11 standard library or available via boost library.